# Send window or image to usb display device C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to send an open window to a usb LCD screen whose documentation is sparse as my knowledge of C ++

This is the API documentation: http://www.lcdinfo.com/usbd480/documentation/api_html/_u_s_b_d480__lib_8h.html, but when I created the .def to create the .lib from the DLL I got this definition which has functions that They are not documented in the API or anywhere in Google:

**USBD480_lib.def**

```
EXPORTS
 ?USBD480_UpdateFPGA@@YAHPEAUDisplayInfo@@@Z
 ?USBD480_UpdateFW@@YAHPEAUDisplayInfo@@@Z
 USBD480_Close
 USBD480_DrawFromBuffer
 USBD480_DrawFullScreen
 USBD480_DrawFullScreenBGRA32
 USBD480_DrawFullScreenRGBA32
 USBD480_DrawLine
 USBD480_DrawRect
 USBD480_GetDisplayConfiguration
 USBD480_GetNumberOfDisplays
 USBD480_GetSWDRegisters
 USBD480_GetTouchPosition
 USBD480_GetTouchReport
 USBD480_LoadParameterStore
 USBD480_Open
 USBD480_ReadParameterStore
 USBD480_SaveParameterStore
 USBD480_SetAddress
 USBD480_SetBrightness
 USBD480_SetFrameStartAddress
 USBD480_SetLEDs
 USBD480_SetSWDRegisters
 USBD480_SetStartupImage
 USBD480_SetStreamDecoder
 USBD480_SetTouchMode
 USBD480_UpdateLEDs
```

I guess my code is going to be a mess and I'm probably not doing anything right, since I'm actually a web developer and I really don't know how to deal with buffers, pointers, and these C ++ features. In this code I try to send an image, without success of course, the only thing that works is that it does adjust the brightness of the screen, so it is connecting correctly, therefore, I am doing something wrong when sending the image.

**USBD480_lib.h** (Created by me)

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

#define     USBD480_API                     _declspec(dllimport);
#define     USBD480_OK                      1;
#define     USBD480_ERROR                   0;
#define     USBD480_OPEN_WITH_USERNAME      0x01;

typedef struct {
    char Name;
    char SerialNumber;
    uint32_t Width;
    uint32_t Height;
    uint32_t PixelFormat;
    uint32_t Handle;
    uint32_t Version;
}DisplayInfo;

typedef struct {
    uint16_t y;
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t z1;
    uint16_t z2;
    uint8_t pen;
    uint8_t pressure;
    uint8_t reserved;
}TouchReport;


enum PIXEL_FORMAT {
    PF_1BPP = 0, PF_1BPP_DS, PF_2BPP, PF_4BPP,
    PF_8BPP, PF_16BPP_RGB565, PF_16BPP_BGR565, PF_32BPP
};

extern "C" int USBD480_GetNumberOfDisplays(void);
extern "C" int USBD480_GetDisplayConfiguration(uint32_t index, DisplayInfo * di);
extern "C" int USBD480_Open(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t flags);
extern "C" int USBD480_Close(DisplayInfo * di);
extern "C" int USBD480_DrawFullScreen(DisplayInfo * di, uint8_t * fb);
extern "C" int USBD480_DrawFullScreenRGBA32(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t * fb);
extern "C" int USBD480_DrawFullScreenBGRA32(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t * fb);
extern "C" int USBD480_SetBrightness(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t brightness);
extern "C" int USBD480_SetTouchMode(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t mode);
extern "C" int USBD480_SetAddress(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t address);
extern "C" int USBD480_SetFrameStartAddress(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t address);
extern "C" int USBD480_DrawFromBuffer(DisplayInfo * di, uint8_t * fb, uint32_t size);
extern "C" int USBD480_GetTouchReport(DisplayInfo * di, TouchReport * touch);
extern "C" int USBD480_GetTouchPosition(DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t * x, uint32_t * y);
extern "C" int USBD480_SetStartupImage(DisplayInfo * di, uint8_t * buffer, uint32_t size);
int USBD480_UpdateFPGA(DisplayInfo * di);
int USBD480_UpdateFW(DisplayInfo * di);
```

**MainProgram.cpp**

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "USBD480_lib\\USBD480_lib.lib")


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "USBD480_lib.h"

DisplayInfo MyDisplay;

int main()
{
    int width = 480;    // Width device resolution
    int height = 272;   // Height device resolution
    
    std::ifstream myFile;
    std::streamsize size;
    
    myFile.open("D:\\windows-apps\\iracing-controller\\dev\\src\\assets\\general\\logo-100x100.png", std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);
    if (!myFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "No pudo abrisse la imagen";
        return 0;
    }
    const uint32_t BLOCK_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
    char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
    myFile.read(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE);
    
    int displays = USBD480_GetNumberOfDisplays();
    if (displays < 1)
    {
        printf("No displays found\n\r");
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Obtenemos la configuración del display
    int ret = USBD480_GetDisplayConfiguration(0, &MyDisplay);
    
    // Abrimos el display
    ret = USBD480_Open(&MyDisplay, 0);
    if (ret != 1) {
        printf("Unable to open Display\n\r");
    }
    
    USBD480_SetAddress(&MyDisplay, 0);
    USBD480_SetFrameStartAddress(&MyDisplay, 0);
    USBD480_SetBrightness(&MyDisplay, 255);
    USBD480_DrawFullScreen(&MyDisplay, (uint8_t*)atoi(buffer));
    USBD480_UpdateFW(&MyDisplay);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to send an image because I can't think of how I could do with the functions that the API offers me to send a window (I have seen an application that sends a browser window), so another solution that I have come up with if I can't send the window is to capture it and send the image of the capture (window captures will be done with C #) every 50ms. In any case I get lost and I don't know how to send the data to the screen through the API.

I guess you should use some of these functions:

```cpp
USBD480_DrawFullScreen (DisplayInfo * di, uint8_t * fb)
USBD480_DrawFullScreenRGBA32 (DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t * fb)
USBD480_DrawFullScreenBGRA32 (DisplayInfo * di, uint32_t * fb)
USBD480_DrawFromBuffer (DisplayInfo * di, uint8_t * fb, uint32_t size)
```

I have tried with all of them and nothing, I have even tried to set the boot image with this function

```cpp
USBD480_SetStartupImage (DisplayInfo * di, uint8_t * buffer, uint32_t size)
```

Another interesting option that would also work for me instead of what is described above would be to be able to convert this USB screen into a second monitor, but I imagine that being LCD I do not know, I do not know, I am ignorant in these things.

Comment: Your `#define` statements have `;` at the end. You probably don't want those.

Comment: Does the code compile? If so, do you see anything on the display?

Comment: Yes the code compiles and I can change the brightness to the screen, but I am not able to print anything @JohnnyMopp

Comment: You have to parse the png file - possibly using a library like libpng. Also, you probably want to draw with `USBD480_DrawFullScreenRGBA32` since will most likely be the pixel format of the png.

Comment: I will try it @johnnyMopp